# nodejs and ejs : "var" is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

In app.js I work with an npm to get information from a youtube video, the problem is that when I try to pass key information such as Title and Thumbnail to my index.ejs file it gives me an error of data is notdefined, I will greatly appreciate your help.

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const youtubeinfo = require("yt-scraper")
const path = require('path')
const app = express()




app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.set("view engine","ejs")
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views')) 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get("/",(req,res)=> {
    res.render("index")
})



app.post("/convert",(req,res) => {
    
    var url = req.body.url
    var data = youtubeinfo.videoInfo(url,
        options = { detailedChannelData: true } )
        console.log(data)
        
        
        data.then(data => {
            
            console.log("=== VIDEO INFO ===")
            console.log(data)
            res.render("index", {datos:data})
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("=== ERROR ===")
            console.log(err)
            console.log("error")
            res.render("error")
        })
        
                
            
                                                                                           
    })            
                   
app.listen(5000, ()=> {
    console.log("server inciated in port 5000")
})
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Descargar Videos y Musica de Youtube y mas</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="encabezado">
            <nav class="navegacion">
                <li class="li1">
                    <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/">
                        <span>
                            "  Redes "
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="li2">
                    <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/">
                        <span>
                            " Contacto " 
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="li3">
                    <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/">
                        <span>
                            "   Mas  " 
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </nav>
            
        </header>
        <main>
            
            <div class="main-div">
                <h1 class="main-titulo">
                    Youtube MP3 Y MP4
                </h1>
                <form action="/convert" method="POST" class="contenedor-formulario">
                    
                    <input type="search" name="url" placeholder="Yourube URL" class="url-input">
                    <button class="convertir">CLICK ME</button>
                    <img src="<%=datos.thumbnails[0].url%>" alt="" class="miniatura">
                    <h1 class="titulo-video" target="_blank" href="<%=datos.url%>">
                    <span><%=datos.title%></span>
                    </h1>
                    
                   
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**error.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Error al convertir :(</h1>
    <h2>¿A que se debe esto?</h2>
    <p>Intentaste introducir una Url invalida</p>
    <br>
    <p>Intentaste introducir un Url de Youtube Short por lo que por el momento no es admitido (pagina aun en desarrollo)</p>
    <br>
    <p>El Url ingresado no pertenece a la plataforma de Youtube</p>
    <img src="" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

*THIS IS THE ERROR THAT RUNS ME**

```
ReferenceError: C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\views\index.ejs:51
    49|                     <input type="search" name="url" placeholder="Yourube URL" class="url-input">

    50|                     <button class="convertir">CLICK ME</button>

 >> 51|                     <img src="<%=datos.thumbnails[0].url%>" alt="" class="miniatura">

    52|                     <h1 class="titulo-video" target="_blank" href="<%=datos.url%>">

    53|                     <span><%=datos.title%></span>

    54|                     </h1>


datos is not defined
    at eval ("C:\\Users\\ROYER\\Desktop\\practica\\views\\index.ejs":12:25)
    at index (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:36)
    at exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\app.js:20:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ROYER\Desktop\practica\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Error's pretty clear? You didn't pass anything called `datos` as context variable to your render call. You only pass that in one place, but you have _lots_ of render calls. So fix the one that's missing the context.

Comment: how? help me pls :(

Comment: What do you mean "how"? Did you write this code? If you have EJS that relies on context variables then just like that line `res.render("index", {datos:data})`  that you already have and passes `datos` as a context variable, you have to pass in your context variables for _every_ render that renders a template with variables.

Comment: that is to say that I can only render an ejs with context variables?

Comment: No, the concept is very straight forward: _if_ the template you're rendering relies on pulling data from variables, then your render call should have a context object that provides those variables. It's just code: if you have code that relies on `x` and you don't provide `x` in that code's scope, you get an error because you're accessing a non-existent variable. But if your template doesn't have any code that relies on context variables, then you obviously don't need to pass any variables for that template to render.

Comment: As I understood, I had to pass the context to my first render? , I did it like this and I keep getting an error ... app.get("/",(req,res)=> {
    
    res.render("index", {datos:data})
})

Comment: every render for a template that relies on variables needs those variables passed in. If you've updated your code, update your post with the updated code, and the updated error (and if it's a new error, _after_ you (re)searched that new error).

Comment: but when I change the second render of the TRY and CATCH for another EJS file it accepts me and no errors come out, but I want the data obtained to be refreshed in the same index.ejs and I get an error of "data is not defined, when I in the TRY of the app.js I put data: data as it should supposedly be executed.

Comment: I just understood what you were saying, about what data nothing is happening to it, because what the try(data) does is shown by the console, which practically shows a json with the "id", "title" , "thumbnail" . but how could I pass that data to my data variable?, help

Comment: You now have enough information to form a [mcve]: almsot none of the things you're showing are still relevant, reduce this to a single route with a single short template that still shows off the problem.

Comment: i did this but i still get the same error: datos = {
                id: id,
                title: title,
                thumbnails: thumbnails
            }
            res.render("index", {datos:datos})

Comment: No: _actually form a [mcve]_ and then update your post. The MCVE exercise is not for use, _it's for you_, you need to actually sit down, and (after copying your code first) start throwing away all the parts that do work, or don't contribute to the problem because _that is how you find the problem_. So: show us you forced yourself to work through that exercise and update your post accordingly.

Comment: but I just wanted a little help on my code :(

Comment: I know, but Stackoverflow is not just about what you want, you're expected to put work into debugging your problem because 10 years from now someone else is going to find your post and you are 100% on the hook to make sure they can understand the problem and whether it's the same as their problem. That's why you're expected to have done all this [before you posted](/help/how-to-ask). Those posting guidelines are there for a reason.

Answer (score -1):

in my case when I get this error I just need to restart my node application. Hope helps. Regards

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33150330)